# Jquery Mobile links stopped working for pages

Tags: html, mobile, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, anchor

I have a jquery mobile site in developement at http://www.ab-mobile-apps.com/app/fcs/index.html

The issuse is that the links from the main menu recently stopped working.  The browser recognizes them but upon a click of the link nothing happens exept for the service link.  I am using JQMobileRC 1.1 as I have with other sites with out any issues.

If anyone has any input It would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Does it help if you comment-out the PhoneGap include since you're testing in a web browser?

Comment: Nope, Didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could be running into this [issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3723).  If so, you need to back up to version 1.0.1 or move forward to the latest bleeding edge.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue (at  the time of this reply, latest jqm version is 1.4.2) and this solved it for me so far :

1) links pointing to a different page within you domain / app : data-ajax="false"

```
<a href="map.html" data-ajax="false"> ... </a>
```

2) links pointing to a different domain : rel="external"

```
<a href="http://www.abcd.xyz/thing.html" rel="external"> ... </a>
```